QGIS - qgis2threejs exporter not displaying layers
I'm new to using the qgis2threejs exporter. I'm trying to use a satellite base map and then my point data has x, y, z.
They appear as expected in QGIS, but aren't appearing in the  qgis2threejs exporter? Would anyone know why this would be?
I have also restarted the QGIS window as per the prompt, but no luck


@Babel yes as I mentioned in my original post

Please specify which QGIS version you are using.
